# Mysql very slow on dropping indexes

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a dedicated server (Intel® Core™ i7-2600 Quadcore incl. Hyper-Threading Technology 16GB DDR3, 2 x 3 TB SATA 6 Gb/s HDD 7200 rpm (Software-RAID 1)) and have installed nginx+apache+mysql from debian stable.

I have a db with a table of 2+ million rows (around 400MB of data). When I drop an index db is very slow. For example I am dropping now an index in a single column for around 8 minutes. From iotop I see mysql has around 8Mb/sec. Isn't this too slow?

Comment: no. It' a simple mysql server and a simple index

Answer (score 1):

When you are altering a table (including adding or dropping an index) in innodb, the whole table is rewritten on the disk. (data is copied, indexes are regenerated). This does not happen if you use  InnoDB Plugin in MySQL 5.1, but by default MySQL 5.1 is not setup with InnoDB Plugin but with the old build-in InnoDB.

Comment: I use innodb but I believe it's the old one since I didn't do anything than default settings. But why does it take so much time? The whole table is 380-400MB. It's not that much data is it?

Comment: Darhazer is right. A lot of the time is spent rebuilding the remaining indexes.